# Dynamic [routerLink] binding with Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular10, angular11

I have the below value with `routerLink` and `queryParams`. Trying to bind the value in the HTML

```
anchorValue : string = `<a [routerLink]="['../category/new ']" [queryParams]="{ query: 'category' }" routerLinkActive = "router-link-active"> Add category</a>`
```

HTML

```
<mat-hint [innerHTML]="anchorValue"></mat-hint>
```

This does bind the value to the `mat-hint`, but the anchor link is not working. Any idea how can I achieve this ?

If I used the below code

```
<mat-hint>
  {{anchorValue}}
</mat-hint>
```

I am getting the below output

[image]

Comment: this isn't gona work. why are you using `innerHTML` instead of just putting the a tag inside the mat-hint tag?

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` isn't going to set angular bindings properly. just put it inside the `mat-hint` tag:

```
<mat-hint>
  <a [routerLink]="['../category/new ']" [queryParams]="{ query: 'category' }" routerLinkActive = "router-link-active"> Add category</a>
</mat-hint>
```

use `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` directives as appropriate to modify the template.

Comment: Well I used the code as you have mentioned, facing the issue updated on the question

Comment: [routerLink]="['../category/new ']" and [queryParams]="{ query: 'category' }" are dynamic. This should not be hard code. Sometime on the <mat-hint> there will be only text not HTML content

Comment: then bind to them dynamically `[routerlink]="anchorLink"` and use `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` directives appropriately to modify the template. You could get a more complete answer if you show what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well <mat-hint> may receive sometimes only plain text, not necessary it will receive <a> always. So there is no point of using ngIf and ngSwitch

Comment: there is a point of using `ngIf` if it MIGHT be displaying an anchor tag, clearly. Again, if you show me what you're ACTUALLY trying to accomplish, you can get a more complete answer. But you cannot make angular bindings work correctly with an `innerHTML` binding

Comment: The content on the anchorValue variable is dynamic. It may hold anchorValue = 'some plain text' or anchorValue = `<a [routerLink]="['../category/new ']" [queryParams]="{ query: 'category' }" routerLinkActive = "router-link-active"> Add category</a>`. So using ngif doesn't make sense

Comment: I am sorry, but not quite sure how can I show you. On Add category text there should be hyperlink, something similar <a href="http://localhost:4200/admin/category/new?query= category">Add category</a> and sometime just a simple plain text

Comment: it's pretty simple. show the different states of the `anchorValue` that you're trying to display and how exactly you're trying to use it

Comment: I was using <mat-hint>{{anchorValue}}</mat-hint> with anchorValue= 'Plain text' or anchorValue = `<a [routerLink]="['../category/new ']" [queryParams]="{ query: 'category' }" routerLinkActive = "router-link-active">Add category</a>`

Comment: what you're trying to do is not going to work. period. end of story. stop trying it. your model is not sufficient to express your view in angular. maybe you need another parameter in your model such as `isLink` to run an `ngIf` of to determine the proper template, along with other model variables to fill in the `routerLink` parameters. I cannot give you more without seeing more of your code and how you're acutally trying to use this or why. but I'm done, so good luck